# JQuery $.each fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to write some code that uses `jQuery.each` and it didn't work.

> TypeError: Object function bound(var_args) { return fund.apply(thisObject, args.concat(slice(arguments))); } has no method 'each'

I went onto the documentation page, copied the example code *verbatim*, and got the same error. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: here is the offending code:

```
$.each([52, 97], function(index, value) { alert(index + ":" + value); }) ;
```

Comment: Can you post the offending code?

Comment: Can you show us the code you have?  The code on the jQuery docs works fine.  I think you may be mixing up `$.each(obj, func)` and `$(sel).each(func)`.  They are different methods that do different things.

Comment: No, I know the difference between them, and am definitely not confusing them. It's got to be something else.

Comment: Besides the fact that you missed a `+` between `":"` and `value`, there is no way that code created the above error.... if you have jQuery loaded.  You did load jQuery, right?  Are you 100% sure `$` is jQuery? `$` probably is something else, and *not* jQuery.  Try `jQuery.each(` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you have loaded the jQuery library and that it is ready when you run your code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each([52, 97], function(index, value) {
        alert(index + ":" + value);
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(document).ready` does not mean that jQuery is ready.  jQuery is ready as soon as its `<script>` tag is ran.  `$(document).ready` means the DOM (the `document`) is ready.  I don't think the DOM needs to be ready to loop over an array that has nothing to do with the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot a '+' sign after the colon in the alert.
Try:

```
alert(index + ":" + value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me, but the concatenation failed due to a missing '`+`' in the alert:

```
$.each([52, 97], function (index, value) {
    alert(index + ":" + value);
});
```